# -567 Rebind Authorization error for Auth ID IBM Db2 native stored procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, db2, db2-zos, ibm-data-studio

A user is unable to create a native stored procedure via IBM data studio and faces -567 rebind authorization error for a particular auth id say DBAXXYY.The schema name is also same as the authid

But I am able to create the stored procedure successfully without any issues using the same authid.

Could any of you kindly help in determining what privilege does the other user lack and what privilege I have different to him?  Also, provide the syntax for any grant privilege that will be needed to create the stored procedure from his end using the same authid DBAXXYY.

I tried providing `GRANT BINDADD TO DBAXXYY` to that authid but still it didn't work.

Error :
Create stored procedure returns SQLCODE: -567, SQLSTATE:42591.
DBAXXYY.SP_SAMP: 0: REBIND AUTHORIZATION ERROR USING
DBAXXYY AUTHORITY PACKAGE =
LOCATION.DBAXXYY.SP_SAMP.(V1) PRIVILEGE = CREATE IN.
SQLCODE=-567, SQLSTATE=42501,
DRIVER=4.18.60
DBAXXYY.SP_SAMP - Deploy failed.
DBAXXYY.SP_SAMP - Roll back completed successfully.

Comment: Yes, we both use the same data studio version 4.1.1

Comment: It is located in our group server.  So technically we both use the same data studio but with different IDs.

Comment: Also can you edit the question to add the full text of the exception, in plain text, including all codes

Comment: Sure, give me a day.  I will login to my system and need to copy the exact error code. Thanks for looking at this.

Comment: See also https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/apar/PM59638

Comment: Will check it out and let this thread know

Comment: I have edited and added the error as it is.  Just changed the names so as to hide the actual names of sp and schema etc.

Answer (score 0):

The exception states that the user account lacks the `CREATEIN` privilege on the target schema. There may be other missing privileges, but you will be able to resolve these either by carefully studing the details of each exception, or by comparing your priviliges with those of the other user. Do that by querying the relvant catalog tables.

For the immediate problem, try:
`GRANT CREATEIN ON SCHEMA ... TO ...`
(where the first name is the schema name , and the second name is the other user name).

If , on the other hand, your security configuration uses ROLES then you need to grant that privilege to a role which the other user has.

Documentation [link](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2-for-zos/11?topic=procedures-granting-createin-privilege-schemas-stored), adjust for your version of Db2 and platform.

Comment: Thanks, I will check and let you know if I am.able to resolve the issue

Comment: Thanks Mao, I have found the solution to the problem and posted the solution here.  Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

At last I was able to provide the required privilege to the user and he is now able to create the native stored procedure.

I gave the following grant on the collection DBAXXYY to the auth id DBAXXYY and this solved the problem.

GRANT CREATE IN COLLECTION DBAXXYY TO DBAXXYY; COMMIT;